# mysqli_num_rows() expects paramter though an earlier query on the same page works

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I am getting an error when querying a table in my MySQL database. It's the standard one with mysqli_num_rows when there is no value in the variable that's being passed:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in folder/file.php on line 29
```

Problem is I can't find the syntax error. I've looked at it a ton of times. Here's what my code is:

```
$sql_messages = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to='$userid'";
$result_messages = $mysqli->query($sql_messages);
$num_rows_messages = mysqli_num_rows($result_messages);
```

I tried a fetch array but that gave me the similar error. Nothing is getting passed into $result_messages I suppose. I echo'ed out $userid and that has a value and I've checked my database and there is a table 'messages' with a field 'to'. I'm connected to the right database because I have this code before this query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname='$firstname' && lastname='$lastname'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

And that works fine. It is the third query on the page, is there some sort of limit? Does anyone see a syntax error that I'm overlooking? Thanks, sorry if it's a small little error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `$mysqli->query()` returned boolean `FALSE`, which, [according to the `mysqli::query()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), it does when an error happens. You can get more detail on the error by accessing [`$mysqli->errno`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) and [`$mysqli->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

I'm guessing that the root of the problem lies in the query which references a column called `to`, which is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Try surrounding the word `to` in your query with backticks. Like this:

```
$sql_messages = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `to`='$userid'";
```

Really, though you should avoid naming columns and tables reserved words. Consider renaming the column if feasible.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. It was the use of the word 'to'. I didn't realize that was already reserved. I ran the error messages and nothing came back so that was a good catch. It's good to know, I need to make sure to make my fields a little more unique in the future...

Comment: As a sidenote, the way you're constructing your queries (by string concatenation), you're creating [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1). Consider using mysqli prepared statements, or PDO if possible.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've been told about PDO and I will look into it. I'm kinda starting from scratch. Thanks so much for your help!